# Why my dataTables in bootstrap don't see the data included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to create a dynamic table in bootstrap/jquery, similar to [this one](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) 
In this example the data is hardcoded, so I thought about changing it with the data that comes from json. Additionally, each row in table has to have a hyperlink added, so my jquery code is as follows:

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
        });   

var data = '[{"number":"1","id":"2","price":"100.70","date":"2015-10-18 03:00:00","hidden":"21"},
{"number":"2","id":"2","price":"88.20","date":"2015-10-18 04:00:00","hidden":"22"}]';

    json = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(json, function(i, v) {
  $('<tr/>', {
    html: [$('<td/>', {
      text: v.number
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.id
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.price
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.date
    }), $('<td/>', {
      html: [
        $('<a/>', {
          href: '#',
          class: 'show-details',
          text: 'show details',
          data: { id: v.hidden },
          click: function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            console.log(id);
            alert(id);
          }
        })
      ]
    })]
  }).appendTo('#dataTables-example tbody')
})
```

In my html I hardcoded the header of the table:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>number</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>date</th>
                    <th>show details</th>
                    <th style="display:none;">hidden identifier</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

and later on thanks to my script I'm appending rows to the table. Simple as that.
However, as you can see in my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uo8rc5qL/6/

there is a problem, because since the data is not hardcoded, the table thinks there are no rows and displays the specific message there `No data available in table`. Also, when I click any column name to sort that data - content disappears, since the table thinks there's nothing to display after sorting...
How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always* go through the API! Insert new rows using `table.row.add([..])` instead of the jQuery `$('<tr>', {...` approach :

```js
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
   var row = table.row.add([v.number, v.id, v.price, v.date, '<a>show details</a>']);
   table.cells({ row: row.index(), column: 4 }).nodes().to$().find('a')
      .attr('href', '#')
      .addClass('show-details')
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .data('id', v.hidden)
      .on('click', function() {
          var id = $(this).data('id');
          console.log(id);
          alert(id);
      })
   table.draw();
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/1**

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, one more question - is there a way of doing the text "show details" only clickable, not the whole cell with that string? Also, how can I add the appropriate coursor when user hovers this text (the standard hyperlink one)?

Comment: @user3766930, yeah - my fault, forgot to target the `<a>` element only :(  have updated fiddle and answer with both corrections.

Comment: one more question - I see you're binding data here `.data('id', v.hidden)`, tell me - is it possible to bind more than one value? for example I would like to bind v.hidden as id and v.price as price - is that even possible?

Comment: @user3766930, jQuery actually treats `data-*` as object literals. So you can save the entire item `v` as `data-v` (for example) and retrieve it back as an object literal upon click  ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/2/** - but you can also add multiple `data` attributes if you want that too.  jQuerys `data('x', y)` is just a wrapper for a `data-x="y"` attribute ...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're just adding the data to the table, not the underlying datatable source.  The solution is to let datatables handle the loading of the data:

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                "data": JSON.parse(datasrc),
                "columns": [
                    { data: 'number' },
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'price' },
                    { data: "date" },
                    {
                        "data": "null",
                        "defaultContent": "<a>click</a>"
                    },
                    { data: "hidden" }
                ]
        });
```

Working example: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/uo8rc5qL/17/)

Comment: thanks, that almost works as I want to! can you just tell me if it's possible to show some alert that displays hidden value when user clicks the hyperlink in the table? For example when user clicks it in first row it should alert 21 and in the second row 22..